# Get Last date of month SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to find the last day of a month in the american (mm-dd-yyyy) format for a column which has yymm(nvarchar format).

example:- for 1601---> 01-31-2016

Thank you for help!

Comment: and how would you know when that year was in 20XX or 19XX?

Comment: `DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, column + '01', 12)))`. Not tested. Slapping on another `CONVERT` to get it to `mm-dd-yyyy` format is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @scsimon :- By default 20xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a string of `1601`, we just need to append a `01` because the century will be assumed.  This new string of `160101` can be converted into a date.

**Example**

```
select convert(varchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,YourCol+'01')),101)
 From  YourTable
```

Returns

```
01/31/2016
```

Comment: This works regardless of language setting because `YYMMdd` is one of the few formats that converts independent of language (the slightly safer `YYYYMMdd` is another one). I'd still prefer an explicit `CONVERT` in there myself... you know, for luck.

Comment: @JeroenMostert If 2012+ I would use try_convert() just in case of bogus or unexpected data  i.e. 1699.

Comment: That would also be nice, but the question is about SQL Server 2008, and `TRY_CONVERT` is but a distant dream there. (Do upgrade, people, 2008 is getting close to its tenth anniversary.)

Answer (score 2):

Using convert to get the date of the 1st of the month, then dateadd to get the next month, and one more dateadd to get one day before:

```
DECLARE @D char(4) = '1601'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CONVERT(date, @D + '01', 12)))
```

Result:

```
2016-01-31
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said year 20XX...

```
declare @oddDate nvarchar(4) = '1601'



select
    DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, '20' + cast(YY as varchar(2)) + cast(MM as varchar(2)) + '01') + 1, 0)) as LastDayof20Year
    ,'20' + cast(YY as varchar(2)) + cast(MM as varchar(2)) + '01' as MadeUpDate
from
(select 
    left(@oddDate,2) as YY
    ,right(@oddDate,2) as MM) x
```

**Or simply...**

```
select
    DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, '20' + cast(left(@oddDate,2) as varchar(2)) + cast(right(@oddDate,2) as varchar(2)) + '01') + 1, 0)) as LastDayof20Year
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do the trick...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    CharDate CHAR(4) NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #TestData (CharDate) VALUES 
    ('9801'), ('9902'), ('0012'), ('0202'), ('1005'), ('1503');

--============================================================

SELECT
    FormattedEOM = CONVERT(CHAR(10), em.EndOfMonth, 101)
FROM
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CASE WHEN CAST(LEFT(td.CharDate, 2) AS INT) > 30 THEN '19' ELSE '20' END) ) c (Century)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (DATEFROMPARTS(CONCAT(c.Century, LEFT(td.CharDate, 2)), RIGHT(td.CharDate, 2), 1)) ) fm (FirstOfMonth)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (EOMONTH(fm.FirstOfMonth)) ) em (EndOfMonth);
```

HTH,
Jason

Edit: The following should work with 2008....

```
SELECT
    FormattedEOM = CONVERT(CHAR(10), em.EndOfMonth, 101)
FROM
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CASE WHEN CAST(LEFT(td.CharDate, 2) AS INT) > 30 THEN '19' ELSE '20' END) ) c (Century)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CAST(c.Century + td.CharDate + '01' AS DATE)) ) fm (FirstOfMonth)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (DATEADD(mm, 1, fm.FirstOfMonth)) ) nm (NextMonth)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (DATEADD(dd, -1, nm.NextMonth)) ) em (EndOfMonth);
```

Comment: `EOMONTH` was my first guess as well, but unfortunately that's from SQL Server 2012 onwards (as is `DATEFROMPARTS`) and the question is about SQL Server 2008.